# wget - "No route to host" connection between a device running armbian and android hotspot

Tags: linux, networking, debian, wget

My device running Armbian based on (Debian GNU / Linux 8) is connected with internet through a hot spot that is provided by an android device (mobile network).

Trying the wget command to download a file 
e.g https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.55.0/boost_1_55_0.tar.gz, 
I receive the message "No route to host"

Checking with "nslookup sourceforge.net" the ip is found ... so I think there is not a problem with DNS server...

```
 route -n results: 
 Destination   Gateway       Genmask         ...    iface
 0.0.0.0       192.168.43.1  0.0.0.0                wlan0
 192.168.43.0  0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0          wlan0
```

.

```
Results from ifconfig: 

wlan0: Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr ...
       inet addr:192.168.43.5 Bcast:192.168.43.255 Mask 255.255.255.0
```

Trying to ping the the google address 8.8.8.8 i receive host is unreachable.

What do I miss ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to have ping and wget to work as it should...

I changed the [etc/network/interfaces.default file](https://github.com/armbian/build/blob/master/packages/bsp/common/etc/network/interfaces.default)
as follows:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
#iface wlan0 inet dhcp
address 192.168.43.5
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.43.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
 wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

So, I think it was an issue with the default DNS address ...